# accessing sqlite databases with java

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am trying to develop an app to key out plants which basically involves choosing A or B from a database table which moves you on to another step in the table where you choose C or D etc.

I have written an app to create an `SQLite` database using Android Studio & also created one using DB Browser.

My question is where does the `database` written in Android Studio live and how do I access the one written in DB Handler?
Please keep the answers simple,

Answer (score -1):

i didint understood your question  if you r asking about database in android you can use sqllitehelper class hare you can not see data you have to use device manager to see sql lite saved data if you wana more information about how to create sql lite use this link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tsNgtAdlof8&list=PL44aUQ2QFq0dsmSTp5XJ6CgIIFAMCroWf